# How to hydrate with react application that uses react-router after load?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, server-side-rendering, react-loadable

I was trying to use code-splitting with `react-router` and found that `react-loadable` is adviced in multiple places (https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/guides/code-splitting.md and https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html). Is it possible to combine react-router and react-loadable with server-side rendering. By default my application tries to show loading element right after application has been initialized which defeats the purpose of server-side rendering. Ideally, only on initial page load I would use `ReactDOM.hydrate` function to initialize application (after the right chunk has been loaded) and then just continue using application as usual (showing loading element)

Comment: have you found a solution?